# How a byte array is used get a formatted String from String.format ? And what does formatted string mean in particular?

Tags: java, arrays, string-formatting

```
byte mac[] = ni.getHardwareAddress();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));    

String macAdd = new String(sb);
System.out.println(macAdd);
```

It prints out the MAC address which for my Interface looks like :

```
70-F1-A1-A1-DF-F5
```

Can anyone please explain me the step :

```
String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "")
```

*Particularly* what does the string `%02X%s` mean ?

Comment: Can you please reference the part of Javadoc that discusses this and indicate exactly what in that text you have trouble understanding?

Comment: Did you try to search for various format specifier on google? See the documentation of `String.format` to know about them. `X` is for `Hex`, and `s` is for `String`. Rest is on you to understand.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I do not understand how from the byte array `mac` I am able to get a String `70-F1-A1-A1-DF-F5` and that refers to the statement `sb.append(....)`

Comment: Your 3rd statement I suppose is inside a for loop right?

Comment: @saplingPro.. So, what's the issue? Your for loop is just iterating over your array, and for each array elements, your target statement, is appending a formatted string containing that element to the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: So your question is not realy "what does the string `%02X%s` mean"? Because that part is easy enough to understand. Maybe phrase your question better, I have no idea what exactly is your barrier to understanding.

Answer (score 7):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

% starts a format spec

0 means left-pad with zero

2 means 2 digits wide

X means hexadecimal output

s means string

so we're outputting a two-digit hex number followed by a string.  I know the Formatter javadoc is a bit dense, but this is really what it's for.

Comment: I just figured out a bit more about this -- evidently, though I didn't know it, formatter starts reusing the format elements if it has more output to do after it runs out.  So the two-digit hex followed by a string is repeated for each element of the array, and the ternary operator at the end just determines whether the string being added is a dash or an empty string (so we get dashes between elements, nothing afterwards.  I would still have expected some kind of loop through the array, though -- don't see how I gets a value, much less gets incremented.